# Cordova 5.0 does not generate relase apk

Tags: android, cordova

I created a release-signing.properties file inside platforms/android and in it I put:

```
key.store= ..\..\myfile.keystore
key.alias= alias
key.store.password= password
key.alias.password= password
```

keystore is in my root folder.

I also tried the other way and created a file build.json according to documentation cordova 5.0

```
{
  "android": {
     "debug": {
        "keystore": "myfilekeystore",
         "storePassword": "password",
         "alias": "alias",
         "password" : "password",
         "keystoreType": ""
     },
     "release": {
         "keystore": "myfile.keystore",
         "storePassword": "password",
         "alias": "alias",
         "password" : "password",
         "keystoreType": ""
     }
  }
 }
```

No matter whatever I was doing, cordova always generates android-debug.apk.

```
cordova build --relase
```

doing the same thing

it seems to me that when it comes to files build.json and release-signing.properties everything is in order. If, for example, if I change the path to the key file, Cordova reports an error.
If I change something in the file build.json happening the same thing. Only if the path and other data are correct cordava generates apk
But always generates debug versions.

Anyone can give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it is release

```
cordova build --release
```